# What Is the Proof that a Conjecture of Eisenbud and Evans Implies a Conjecture of Forster?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $B$ be a commutative ring and let $\frak p$ be a prime ideal of $B$. Consider a finitely-generated $B$-module $M$.

Let $\mu_{\frak p}(M)$ be the minimal number of generators of $M_{\frak p}$ as a $B_{\frak p}$-module.

Define $e(M)$ to be $\max\{\mu_{\frak p}(M)+\dim B/{\frak p}\mid {\frak p} \text{ is a prime ideal of }B\text{ such that }\dim B/{\frak p}<\dim B\}$.

The aforementioned Eisenbud-Evans conjecture (which was proven by N. Mohan Kumar) says the following:

Let $B=A[T]$ be a polynomial ring in the variable $T$ over the Noetherian ring $A$.  Then any finitely-generated $B$-module $M$ can be generated by $e(M)$ elements as a $B$-module.

The aforementioned Forster conjecture says the following:

Let $k$ be a field and let $P$ be a prime ideal in the polynomial ring $S=k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ such that $S/P$  is regular.  Then $P$ can be generated by $n$ elements.

N. Mohan Kumar says it is well-known that the Eisenbud-Evans conjecture implies the Forster conjecture, but does not give a reference.

Can someone please provide the proof?  I am interested in an analogue of the Forster conjecture.

*Reference*

N. Mohan Kumar, "On Two Conjectures about Polynomial Rings," *Inventiones Math.* **46** (1978), 225-236.

Comment: Calculate $e(P)$ considering the two sets of prime ideals, those containing $P$ and not containing $P$.

Comment: @Mohan I will try that and see if I can work it out. Thank you!